# How to create a vertical graph using lists

Tags: python, list

```
number_iterations = input('enter how many times: ')
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
list_4 = []
list_5 = []
list_6 = []
list_7 = []
list_8 = []
list_9 = []
list_10 = []
list_11 = []
list_12 = []
n = int(number_iterations)
for i in range (1, n):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    y = random.randint(1,6)
    sum_num = x + y

    if sum_num == 2:
        list_2.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 3:
        list_3.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 4:
        list_4.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 5:
        list_5.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 6:
        list_6.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 7:
        list_7.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 8:
        list_8.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 9:
        list_9.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 10:
        list_10.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 11:
        list_11.append(1)
    elif sum_num == 12:
        list_12.append(1)
two = '* ' * (len(list_2)) 
three = '* ' * (len(list_3)) 
four = '* ' * (len(list_4)) 
five = '* ' * (len(list_5)) 
six = '* ' * (len(list_6)) 
seven = '* ' * (len(list_7)) 
eight = '* ' * (len(list_8)) 
nine = '* ' * (len(list_9))
ten = '* ' * (len(list_10)) 
eleven = '* ' * (len(list_11)) 
twelve = '* ' * (len(list_12)) 
print('2 : ' + two)
print('3 : ' + three)
print('4 : ' + four)
print('5 : ' + five)
print('6 : ' + six)
print('7 : ' + seven)
print('8 : ' + eight)
print('9 : ' + nine)
print('10: ' + ten)
print('11: ' + eleven)
print('12: ' + twelve)
```

Basically what the code does is simulate the rolling of two dice a user defined number of times. The goal is to graph these results. An example output would look like:

```
enter how many times: 100
2 : * * * 
3 : * * * * * * 
4 : * * * * * * * 
5 : * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
6 : * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
7 : * * * * * * * * * * 
8 : * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
9 : * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
10: * * * * * * 
11: * * * * * * 
12: * *
```

This of course is a horizontal bar graph. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that it was a vertical one, with the bars displaying vertically? I've tried using itertools and .zip_longest but it doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to first find the maximum number of asterisks. Then, iterate `row in range(max_asterisks, 0, -1)`.

For each row, you go over your lists, and print an asterisk if the count exceeds the row number, or print a space if not.

For example, this is what I came up with:

```py
# counts is the number of elements in each of your lists

# print(*counts, sep='\t')

for lineno in range(max(counts), 0, -1):
    # 2-12: eleven elements
    for item in range(11):
        # Print only if the count in this column is large enough
        if counts[item] >= lineno:
            print('*', end='')
        # TABs just make formatting easier
        print('\t', end='')
    # Add newline
    print()

# Add the column label
print(*range(2, 13), sep='\t')
```

And the result:

```
                        *                   
                        *                   
                *       *                   
                *   *   *                   
            *   *   *   *   *               
            *   *   *   *   *   *           
            *   *   *   *   *   *           
    *       *   *   *   *   *   *           
*   *       *   *   *   *   *   *           
*   *       *   *   *   *   *   *           
*   *       *   *   *   *   *   *   *       
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *       
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
```